# How to set ownership/permission of PHP site that accessible by the user AND the apache user

Tags: apache-http-server, php, ubuntu-12.04

I'm having problems with my PHP projects within `/var/www` set on permission `www-data:www-data`.

My user can't write to these directories. I've added myself to `www-data` group and have added `chmod -R g+rw /var/www` but still have issues. What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you login again after adding yourself to `www-data`?

Comment: Is my local machine, but yes, I've closed the session, restarted the machine even... No luck

Comment: Show the output of `id`, `stat dirname` (where dirname is whatever dir you're trying to e.g. add a file to), and the exact error message you get. (Add it to the question.)